# How to had space when concatenation a JavaScript sentence

Tags: javascript

I am inserting specific word into a sentence with concatenation but the words a running together with no space between them.

```
var adjective1 = + 'amazing';
var adjective2 = + 'fun';
var adjective3 = + 'entertaining';



var madLib = 'The Intro to JavaScript course is'   + adjective1 +  'james and Julia are so'  + 
adjective2 + 'I cannot wait to work through the rest of this' + adjective3 + 'content!';
console.log(madLib);
```

Comment: Just add a space to the string: `The Intro to JavaScript course is ` <---- space

Comment: Your `adjective` variables are all `NaN`.

Comment: include the space with literal string

Comment: Or add spaces to the adjective strings.

Comment: Consider a [*template literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals): `\`The Intro to JavaScript course is ${adjective1} james and Julia are so...\``.

Answer (score 1):

Just add spaces

```
var madLib = 'The Intro to JavaScript course is '   + adjective1 +  ' james and Julia are so'  + 
adjective2 + 'I cannot wait to work through the rest of this ' + adjective3 + ' content!';
```

You also shouldn't have `+` before the strings in the variable assignments. That will  try to convert the strings to numbers, and will produce `NaN` since they're not numeric.

```
var adjective1 = 'amazing';
var adjective2 = 'fun';
var adjective3 = 'entertaining';
```